# What is wrong with my code, it will not write in ecrire.txt

Tags: c#

`Formulaire.Demander.Valeur` is a popup box where I can write a string.
 All I need to know is why it will not write in my txt file. This is just an exercise for
school!

```
bool bFichierExiste = false;
string sPhrase = "";


bFichierExiste = File.Exists("ecrire.txt"); //Validate if file exist
if (!bFichierExiste)
{
    MessageBox.Show("N'existe pas!");
}
else
{
    StreamWriter fichier = new StreamWriter("ecrire.txt");      
    using (fichier)
    {
        do
        {
            sPhrase = Formulaires.DemanderValeur("Saisie phrase: ");
            fichier.WriteLine(sPhrase); 
            fichier.Flush();                                         
        }
        while (sPhrase != "FIN");
    }
    fichier.Close();                                                    
}
```

Comment: [`using` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Try writing out just "abcd". See if that works.

Comment: Also, how do you know it doesn't write? Are you certain you're looking in the right place? I notice that "ecrire.txt" has no path in it. Maybe it's writing somewhere unexpected

Comment: @JohnSaunders by default it seem it is writing in the "bin/debug" folder. anyway for me it was

Comment: what is Formulaires.DemanderValeur. I tested the code in a console program (see code in my answer) and it should work

Comment: @Fredou: no, it wrote to the current working directory, which starts off being the directory containing the .exe file. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write string to text documents?

Try this.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

this work so what does `DemanderValeur`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool bFichierExiste = false;
        string sPhrase = "";


        bFichierExiste = File.Exists("ecrire.txt"); //Validate if file exist
        if (!bFichierExiste)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("N'existe pas!");
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter fichier = new StreamWriter("ecrire.txt");
            using (fichier)
            {
                do
                {
                    sPhrase = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(sPhrase);
                    fichier.WriteLine(sPhrase);
                    fichier.Flush();
                }
                while (sPhrase != "FIN");
            }
            fichier.Close();
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: DemanderValeur is just to iniate the Type of what will be entered in the txtbox of the Formulaire. i.e DemanderValeur, stand for string, DemanderValeurInt, stand for int.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answers, my problem was in fact the unspecified folder path and also StreamWriter(string) was overwriting my file each time it was closed and reopend. I changed it to StreamWriter(string,Bool) which reopen it in Append mode.

```
        bool bFichierExiste = false;
        string sPhrase = "";


        bFichierExiste = File.Exists("ecrire.txt"); 
        if (!bFichierExiste)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("N'existe pas!");
        }
        else
        {                
                do
                {
                    StreamWriter fichier = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Maxim P. Verreault\\Desktop\\Technique_Informatique\\Automne 2013\\Algo&Prog\\Travaux\\Notions de fichiers TEXTE\\Algorithmes\\ecrire.txt",true);
                    using (fichier)
                    {
                        sPhrase = Formulaires.DemanderValeur("Saisie phrase: ");    
                        fichier.WriteLine(sPhrase);                                 
                        fichier.Flush();
                    }
                    fichier.Close();  
                }
                while (sPhrase != "FIN");

        }
```